# OPENCV resizing for getting image mean value - different result to gimp

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, interpolation, linear-interpolation

at the moment i'm trying to get the average color value of an image. I simply tried to resize the whole image to 1x1 pixel`img2= cv2.resize(img00, (1,1))`and take the rgb values

```
for i in xrange(0,3):
        rgb[i] = img2[0][0][i]
cv2.rectangle(img,(0,0),(100,100),(int(rgb[0]),int(rgb[1]),int(rgb[2])),-1)
```

, but the result was wrong. It just showed the color of the right side like OPENCV would interpolate towards one corner.( The "Result 1x1"-Image shows the rgb values of the pixel after resizing) Likewise I tried to resize the same img with gimp, which also just interpolates the picture and the result showed the right average pixel. I don't really know why OPENCV produces a different result but i really need to fix that. Any ideas? Thanks for help:3[test image for resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYi0o.jpg)&[Result 1x1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYsZd.jpg)

Comment: using `cv2.mean(...)` was too easy?

Comment: it gives me an average value of 128/127/128(is that rgb/bgr?) which isn't the color gimp gave me.

Comment: it's BGR, and actually make a lot of sense that the average of a color image is basically gray. You've probably been mislead by whatever you're doing in GIMP, which is wrong (i.e. you're not computing the mean color of the image)

Comment: cv2.mean is just giving you the average of clean values of an array but not the average of a color. http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=5c734c-1463589399.jpg that's the real average of those two colors produced by gimp

Comment: _clean_ values? Which _two_ colors? It's not to be pedantic, but you need to make much more sense than this ;D

Comment: It gives me the average of all the values but BGR isn't working that way - Gray isn't the average of both, as seen in the link above  (The 2 colors of my test image)

Comment: So, gray **is** the correct mean value. What you get is **not** the correct mean value. Simply, what you need is not the mean. It seems to me that you have the two colored squares, and you want to superimpose one on top of the other, with some transparency effect. `cv2.addWeighted` should help you with this.

Comment: First of all sorry if my english isn't always proberly, i'm german but i'm trying my best :). Yes mathematically it is the right mean value but it's not the right one for the rgb format .cv2.addweighted doesn't help me further as i'm having just one image and addweighted needs two arrays. The test picture is also just one possible case and it should also work with different images. I'm confused why the interpolation of gimp is working and the interpolation of OPENCV isn't.

Comment: How can you prove that the result from gimp is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the right tool/function for your problem. In this case, for OpenCV 2 [`cv.Avg(...)`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#mean), and for OpenCV 3 [`cv2.mean(...)`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#mean).

Also, keep in consideration that default for OpenCV is bgr and not rgb, although I would expect this to have no impact since it's just the name of a variable.

Regarding your code, although I don't reccomend that, it could work if you use as interpolation method [`INTER_AREA`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize).

Comment: I just read the first pixel of my image as there is only one pixel left after resizing. Which format does cv.Avg(...)/cv2.mean(..) give out? The result is 128/127/128 which ist just gray

Comment: @Darxyde That's the average: in bgr, green is 0/0/255, and purple 255/255/0

Comment: Yea but just add those an divide by the number of values isn't the right way   http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=5c734c-1463589399.jpg - this is what gimp is giving out....looks better in my eyes

Comment: @Darxyde could you please explain why taking the sum and dividing by the number of elements is not the correct way of computing the mean?

Comment: @Darxyde What are you trying to compute? The average color is given by the sum of all colors in all pixels divided by the number of pixels. If you are looking for something different, please ask a new question (this I believe is answered).

Comment: it's computing the mean of a number of values but the resulting product in BGR is different - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKnqECcg6Gw explained here

Comment: @Darxyde That's an interesting topic, but here your question is answered: if you simply ask for average, that's what average/mean is. Ask a new question. Make sure you resume the essence of the video without having people forced to actually watch it to understand your question.